# == was not expected at this time ( Batch File )

Tags: if-statement

i'm making a simple .bat file that has some options. but when i use a space as a choice it says. == was not expected at this time. what did i do wrong ?

```
@ECHO off
title AutoMatic Program Install Beta v5 by eric
:ReturnToBaseLine
color 0a
cls
echo Made By The Amazing 
echo[
echo    ____    _       ________         ___                            
echo   / __/___(_)___  /_  __/ /  ___   / _ \_______ ___ ___ _  ___ ____
echo  / _// __/ / __/   / / / _ \/ -_) / // / __/ -_) _ `/  ' \/ -_) __/
echo /___/_/ /_/\__/   /_/ /_//_/\__/ /____/_/  \__/\_,_/_/_/_/\__/_/   
echo[                                                                   
Echo[
Echo   .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-. 
Echo .'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `.
echo[
Echo Wilt u Microsoft Office Installeren(M) of een Anti-Virus Progamma(A) ?
echo[
echo         Of Wilt u Overige Software Instalereren(O) ?
echo[
echo                                  Afsluiten(X)
echo[
Echo   .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-.     .-. 
Echo .'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `._.'   `.
echo[
echo[
set /p choice=Keuze : 
if not '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" Is niet een geldige optie
if '%choice%'=='M' goto Office
if '%choice%'=='m' goto Office
if '%choice%'=='A' goto Anti
if '%choice%'=='a' goto Anti
if '%choice%'=='O' goto Overig
if '%choice%'=='o' goto Overig
if '%choice%'=='X' exit
if '%choice%'=='x' exit
Pause
Goto :ReturnToBaseLine
```

Comment: Inhibiting the impulse to write a "gaaaaaaa" comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space is a default separator, so batch sees if <kbd>'</kbd>[separator]<kbd>'</kbd>==''

To enclose a string containing spaces and other separators, use **Rabbits Ears** thus: <kbd>"</kbd>%choice%<kbd>"</kbd>

Also : you can use the `/i` switch wit `if` to make the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: so i must chance all '%choice%' with "%choice%" ?
sorry i am kinda new to making batch files.

Comment: Yes - wherever you have `'string'` change it to `"string"`

Answer (score 0):

For paths enclosed in double quotes use

```
if [%1]==[]
```

instead of

```
if "%1"==""
```

which will fail when you try calling your `try.bat` with a quoted param and spaces

```
try "hello world"
```

The error given if you use `if "%1"==""` is: `"== was not expected`

Using [] or any other delimiter that isn't part of the JS language (don't use quote, double quote, (, =, +, {,